# How to check out code for SqueakSource?

Tags: repository, smalltalk, squeak, monticello

I created new asserts in the package KernelTests-Numbers of squeak. I cannot find a way to check out these to Squeaksource (a repo) or with monticello. How to check out new tests into the repository http://source.squeak.org/trunk to spread it to the community?

Thanks for the answers in advance.

*EDIT*

Thanks Tobias.

Here is the Monticello-Code for the *Inbox*:

```
MCHttpRepository
location: 'http://source.squeak.org/inbox'
user: ''
password: ''
```

*EDIT 2*

Thanks Bert for the Step-by-Step-Manual and screencast link.

Regards,
bartak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are basically

1. Update so you have the latest trunk versions
2. Check the package changes against Trunk repo
3. Make sure only the methods you actually touched are listed
4. Save your package to the Inbox repo, giving it a reasonable commit message

Here is a video I made about how to submit a new package. Note this is for Etoys, so whenever I talk about the "etoys" repo you need to use "trunk", and instead of "etoys-inbox" you use "inbox". The relevant part is from about 1:20 to 4:00 min:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QKmfI4taGo#t=1m20s

Answer (score 2):

You put into another repository, called *the inbox*:

```
http://source.squeak.org/inbox
```

From there, Squeak core developers can merge into the `trunk` repository.
The whole process is described in [A New Community Development Model](http://squeakboard.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/a-new-community-development-model/).

You probably want to talk about your changes on [squeak-dev](http://forum.world.st/Squeak-Dev-f45488.html).

Comment: Thanks Tobias. And how to checkout my tests in Squeak?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Sorry Tobias. How to push my code into Inbox-Repo with Monticello in Squeak? What are the steps to do it?

Comment: @bert-freudenberg has posted a very nice step-by-step way. You should use that.